# Why indexOf doesn't work as expected?

Tags: java, list

[image]
I have `labels` which is a list of `String` and is equal to `[0,1]`. However the following line returns `-1` while I expect it to return `1`. Any idea what could be wrong or missing?
definition:
maxLabel is an integer initially set to -1.
    public List labels;

where the unexpected result happens, while `maxLabel` is equal to 1:

```
int maxLabelIndex=labels.indexOf(maxLabel);
```

Comment: Please post the content of `labels`. `indexOf` returns -1 if the list *does not* contain the element.

Comment: `-1` means the item isn't being found in the list. Double check the values of your variables.

Comment: as I mentioned this is content of labels before executing that line [0,1]

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart I am checking the value of my variables using Eclipse debugger and they are as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: I believe you do mean that the content is `["0","1"]` and that `maxLabel="1"`. (Note the double quotes to denote that these are indeed Strings).

Comment: `maxLabel` is the **String** 1?

Comment: Please create an actual test-case. Otherwise all we can do is guess.

Comment: Can you show us maxLabel too - the only guess we can make (as mentioned in the answer below) is that maxLabel is numeric.

Comment: Show us the actual code. I'm pretty sure the problem is that you are passing the *Integer* 1 to the indexOf method (because it takes any object type, not just String), and the Integer 1 does not equal the string "1"

Comment: @MonaJalal What exactly do you want your code to do? Return the maximum value from your list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More formally, returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null

In your case the index of element `"1"`  is `1`, thats why you will get 1. **BUT** if you will pass `int maxLabel = 1;` notice that maxLabel is declared as type `int` then you will get -1 because Collection of strings doesn't contains an object of type Integer. 
 
Basically indexOf method take as parameter `o` of type `Object`. Whenever you pass a different Object type (e.g. you declared your `List` of type `String` and you are checking for **different** types like `Integer,Double,int,long, etc.`), you can expect to get `-1`

Comment: Yeah you are correct. I converted the maxLabel to String and now it is working fine.